# Audio of HDMI from a 5870

Tags: graphics-card, hdmi

Quick question, thinking of running an HDMI cable from my PC to my TV, use my computer to watch Hulu and Netflix and whatnot as opposed to the buggy PS3 apps.  Maybe play some Steam games on the big screen.  Etc.

Not sure if an HDMI cable from my graphics card will send audio as well, or will I need to run a separate audio cable?  It's a Radeon 5870.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure does.

> [From AMD](http://www.amd.com/us/products/desktop/graphics/ati-radeon-hd-5000/hd-5870/Pages/ati-radeon-hd-5870-overview.aspx)
>   Integrated HD audio controller
>   Output protected high bit rate 7.1 channel surround sound **over HDMI with no additional cables required**
>   Supports AC-3, AAC, Dolby TrueHD and DTS Master Audio formats

AMD has supported this since the 4xxx series consistently. :D

Comment: Huzzah! And such.